# How oracle sequence works internally?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, triggers, sequence

I wan to know how sequence for a table works internally in oracle database. Specially how they increment value of sequence.

Are they use trigger for incrementing value of sequence or anything else???

Comment: Sequences don't have triggers - but a trigger might get a value from a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not handle sequences as other objects, like tables. 
If you insert 100 records using the NEXTVAL and issue a ROLLBACK, 
this sequence does not get rolled back. 
Instead, 100 records will have incremented the sequence. 
The next insert will have the 101-st value of the sequence. 
This will lead to "spaces" in the sequence. That allows for multiple people to
safely use sequences without the risk of duplicates.
If two users simultaneously grab the NEXTVAL, they will be
assigned unique numbers. Oracle caches sequences in memory. 
The init.ora parameter SEQUENCE_CACHE_ENTRIES defines the cache size.

Comment: Note: SEQUENCE_CACHE_ENTRIES is obsolete in the most recent versions of Oracle.  You can use the alter sequence command to change the cache size, if required. An example of the modification of the cache size for a sequence called seq: Alter sequence seq cache 100;

Comment: Another Note:  Values of a sequence are generated in an autonomous transaction. Oracle caches 20 values,by default, before generating the new ones in a new transaction. Having a lot of inserts will generate a lot of sequence values and will result in a lot of I/O on the sequence. Run benchmarks to find a good value for your sequence cache in high-throughput scenarios.